# Dynamic TableView Swift 3 With Beginning Graph

Tags: dynamic, static, swift3, tableview

I have a tableview that gets its information from a database and returns it as "results. The TableView Data Source is as follows:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if isLoading {
        print("isLoading")
        return 1
    }else if results.count == 0 {
        return 1
    } else {
        print("results Count:", results.count)
        return results.count
    }
}
enum MyRows: Int {
    case graph = 0
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
               cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if indexPath.row == MyRows.graph.rawValue {
        let graphcell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: TableViewCellIdentifiers.GraphCell,for: indexPath) as! PendingGraphCell
        graphcell.configureForGraph(graphData: self.graphData)
        return graphcell
    }
    print(indexPath)
    if isLoading {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: TableViewCellIdentifiers.loadingCell, for:indexPath)
        return cell
    } else if results.count == 0 {
        return tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: TableViewCellIdentifiers.nothingFoundCell,for: indexPath)
    } else {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: TableViewCellIdentifiers.ResultCell,for: indexPath) as! ResultCell
        let result = results[indexPath.row];
        print(result)
        cell.configureForResult(result: result)
        return cell
    }
}
```

The tableView works perfectly when I remove the "Graph" Cell:

```
if indexPath.row == MyRows.graph.rawValue {
    let graphcell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: TableViewCellIdentifiers.GraphCell,for: indexPath) as! PendingGraphCell
    graphcell.configureForGraph(graphData: self.graphData)
    return graphcell
}
```

So I need to update the number of rows to include the 1st static row. Did that and then I receive an error.

```
Index out of range.
```

Table Views really confuse me, I've been working on this all night. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:

I edited the count to 4 and still got the same error. And results.count = 3

Here is the error:

```
Index out of range
```

Here is the Exception Breakpoint where it fails

```
let pendingResult = pendingResults[indexPath.row];
```

Also, my output cell for the graph is different than the one for the results cell. The results cell is 44 and so every other cell in my table is set to 44.. What gives?

Denis Angell

Answer (score 0):

try this code.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
                       cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            if indexPath.row == MyRows.graph.rawValue {
                let graphcell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: TableViewCellIdentifiers.GraphCell,for: indexPath) as! PendingGraphCell
                graphcell.configureForGraph(graphData: self.graphData)
                return graphcell
            }

            else{
                var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: TableViewCellIdentifiers.ResultCell,for: indexPath) as! ResultCell

                if isLoading {
                    cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: TableViewCellIdentifiers.loadingCell, for:indexPath)

                } else if results.count == 0 {
                    cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: TableViewCellIdentifiers.nothingFoundCell,for: indexPath)
                } else {
                    cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: TableViewCellIdentifiers.ResultCell,for: indexPath) as! ResultCell

                    let result = pendingResults[indexPath.row];
                    print(result)
                    cell.configureForResult(result: result)

                }

                return cell
            }
        }
```

Comment: Wont this run one or the other? I want my graph cell on top, then I want the results cells to follow... There could be 1 or 27 result cells, however, the graph cell will always be one.

Comment: Looks like results.count is greater than pendingresults.count...try debug by adding correct count return in numberofrowsInSection method..

Comment: Still doesnt work. Also, I have a tableview and its row is 44 and so the height is set for all of them. How can I set two different heights?

Comment: can u just add your printed result.?

Comment: i need to visualise the result data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138782/discussion-between-denis-and-adarshau).